# Не выводятся данные с компонента 1C-Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Пишу свой компонент для вывода номеров телефонов, адресов и разных ссылок! То-есть всего у меня добавлено 3 поля.

```
 Ссылка(HREF), Тип ссылки(TYPE_HREF), Текст(TEXT_FOR_HREF).
```

Вот код файла `component.php`

```
    <?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;

if(!Loader::includeModule("iblock"))
{
    return;
}
$arSelect = Array("ID", "HREF", "TYPE_HREF", "TEXT_FOR_HREF", "PROPERTY_".$arParams["PROPERTY_CODE"]);
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => IntVal($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"]), "ACTIVE"=>"Y", "PROPERTY_".$arParams["PROPERTY_CODE"]."_VALUE" => 'Да');
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($arFields = $res->GetNext())
{
    $arResult[] = $arFields;
}

$this->includeComponentTemplate();?>
```

В файле теперь пытаюсь получить свои данные! То-есть `[HREF],[TYPE_HREF],[TEXT_FOR_HREF]`

Вывожу

```
<?foreach ($arResult as $arItem): ?>
    <?echo $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["HREF"]["VALUE"];?>        
<?endforeach;?>
```

Но данные не выводятся! Проверяю массив     `<?print_r($arItem);?>`

А там только ID и все, нет моих параметров!

```
Array ( [ID] => 22228 [~ID] => 22228 )
```

Comment: Потому что пользовательские свойства запрашиваются с префиксом PROPERTY_: PROPERTY_HREF и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решился вопрос благодаря пользователю [u_mulder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178087/u-mulder)

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "PROPERTY_HREF", "PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF", "PROPERTY_TEXT_FOR_HREF", "PROPERTY_".$arParams["PROPERTY_CODE"]);
```

Данные редактировал в файле `component.php` Массив сразу выводит данные.

```
Array ( [ID] => 22228 [~ID] => 22228 [PROPERTY_HREF_VALUE] => info@ [~PROPERTY_HREF_VALUE] => info@ [PROPERTY_HREF_VALUE_ID] => 136708 [~PROPERTY_HREF_VALUE_ID] => 136708 [PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF_VALUE] => Почта [~PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF_VALUE] => Почта [PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF_ENUM_ID] => 765 [~PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF_ENUM_ID] => 765 [PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF_VALUE_ID] => 174550 [~PROPERTY_TYPE_HREF_VALUE_ID] => 174550 [PROPERTY_TEXT_FOR_HREF_VALUE] => info@ [~PROPERTY_TEXT_FOR_HREF_VALUE] => info@ [PROPERTY_TEXT_FOR_HREF_VALUE_ID] => 136710 [~PROPERTY_TEXT_FOR_HREF_VALUE_ID] => 136710 )
```